# JUnit test a user input to function call

Tags: junit

I want to test the mainMenu of a program which receives user input and calls a function/method depending on the input.

```
public void mainMenu() {
    System.out.println("1. Schedule a meeting");
    System.out.println("2. Book vacation dates");
    System.out.println("3. Check room availability");

try {
            int userInput = Integer.parseInt(inputOutput("Please enter the number that corresponds to the option that you want to proceed with."));

        if (userInput >= 0 && userInput <=6) {
            if (userInput == 1) {
                this.scheduleMeeting();
            }
            if (userInput == 2){
                this.scheduleVacation();
            }
            if (userInput == 3){
                this.checkRoomAvailability();
         } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter a number from 0 - 6");
            this.mainMenu();
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number from 0 - 6");
        this.mainMenu();
    }
}
```

To test the userInput I think it would be something like:

```
    ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream("2".getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);
```

But how would I test the expected result when it's a function call? Should I be using Mockito and how would I implement it?

Answer (score 1):

1) You can make a 'mock' test. Read Mockito.

2) You can pass an input parameter of user like parameter of method.

3) just use fake value to test. Input your own integer and write a test. You need just to check if method work correct and doesn't matter who input this value.

Comment: So I've been looking around, would it be something like this: when(mockedObject.scheduleMeeting()).thenReturn("scheduleMeeting called") ?
Would this work? And what do you mean at 2?

Answer (score 0):

you can check an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/6416179/edit)

Different approach can be make this method more testable by passing IN and OUT as parameters:

```
public static int testUserInput(InputStream in,PrintStream out) {
   Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(in);
    out.println("Give a number between 1 and 10");
    int userInput = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (userInput >= 0 && userInput <=6) {
        if (userInput == 1) {
            this.scheduleMeeting();
        }
        if (userInput == 2){
            this.scheduleVacation();
        }
        if (userInput == 3){
            this.checkRoomAvailability();
     } else {
        System.out.println("Please enter a number from 0 - 6");
        this.mainMenu();
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a number from 0 - 6");
    this.mainMenu();
}

    return input;
}
```